# How do I recreate this aligment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm creating my title page for my thesis I've almost finisced but I can't allign like I want my text.

This a picture of what I want to do[image]

That's what I tried to do:

```
\begin{align*}
&\text{Relatore}  &\text{Lureando} \\
&\text{Chiar.mo nameofprof} &\text{nameofstud}\\
& &\text{Matricola: 0089898}
\end{align*}
```

But the aligment are not right. What I do wrong?

I've also tried this:

```
\large{Relatore} \hfill \large{Lureando} \\
\large{prof} \hfill \large{stud}\\
\hfill \large{Matricola: 0089898}
```

Comment: Maybe a  `tabular`?

Comment: `\large` doesn't take an argument but is a switch, the correct syntax would be `{\large Relatore}`.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the `frontespizio` package?

Comment: @egreg yes but I can't customize it enough so I did it from scratch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few options:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  Relatore\\
  Prof. C. Xavier
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  Laureanda\\
  Foo\\
  Bar
\end{tabular}

Or\bigskip

\noindent
Relatore \hfill Lureando\\
Prof. C. Xavier \hfill Foo\\
\mbox{}\hfill Bar

Or\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[]{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{}}
  Relatore & Laureanda\\
  Prof. C. Xavier & Foo\\
  & Bar
\end{tabular*}

Or\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[]{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
  Relatore & Laureanda\\
  Prof. C. Xavier & Foo\\
  & Bar
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `minipage` and a `t`op alignment, and `flushright` everything in the second minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent% <- Thanks Mico!
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Relatore

Chiar.mo nameofprof
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\flushright
Lureando

nameofstud

Matricola: 0089898
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The output of the above is this:

[image]

Comment: this align the text correctly, but I also need to align it with the left and right margin of my page(right margit is correct but I think that it's a case)

Comment: Don't forget to insert `\noindent` immediately before the first `\begin{minipage}`.

Comment: @malloc You can simply `flushright` the second minipage. Your example picture doesn't seem to have this alignment though...